# Declaring a property with an empty set in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using entity framework database first and extending the AutoGenerated partial classes. Is the following alright if I need to also set the property in my application based on certain scenarios? It just feels strange because I am usually setting a private property in my set, but don't think I need to here with EF.

```
public string FullName
{
  get
  {
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
  }
  set
  {

  }
}
```

In my application FullName is a bound field in a grid. When I bind the grid from the database it works fine as a read-only property. But there is an instance where I have to dynamically create an objectlist of CustomerContact and pass it to another page in a Session variable and bind the grid in memory on the new page. Since the bound field for the same column in the grid on the new page needs to be FullName it seems like I have no option but to allow a Set on this property...

Comment: If you cannot *set* FullName, it should not have a setter. Remove it.

Comment: I need to be able to set it in my code is what I am saying. I want to know if it is alright to do this.

Comment: Well I wouldn't do it like that. I assume to are talking split(' ') and set FirstName, LastName. The amount of validation required and the potential ambiguity, e.g. FullName = 'Hopkinson, Anthony John' would make me well nervous.

Comment: My question was more about how set {} is empty and if this is alright if I need to set it in my code.

Comment: Make FullName a class or structure instead of a string then. You could add formatting to it then.

Comment: Fill it in or remove it, otherwise anyone who uses your code is going to call you names.

Comment: Maybe I should explain the situation to why it can't be a ReadOnly property... FullName is a DataField in one of the grids in my application. When the grid pulls from the database it uses the GET and pulls fine. But in my code I have to dynamically create the object list that is bound to the grid and manually set FullName which is why I need a set. Does this make sense?

Comment: How about settings the Firstname and Lastname and leave the property without a setter? If it does not work then I would go with a DTO object as mentioned in Tony's answer. To map the data to the DTO you can use some mapping library like AutoMapper unless you want to do it manually.

Comment: Complete stupidity on my part... I wasn't thinking about this properly.. Even if I have to set this property in the code just set the actual FirstName and LastName properties... then my get will always work.... Having a bad day lol. Sorry guys. Now it is just a readonly property like it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments. No you should not leave it empty.

Think about it from a user point of view.
You can say MyThingy.FullName = "Fred Blogs". It compiles, it throws no exceptions and does absolutely nothing. 
Other people's code, which includes your own in a couple of months, is hard enough to understand without drilling big holes in your cortex before you start.

To beef up from your last comment. No it doesn't make sense to have one class that has two completely different behaviours. There are lots of ways to deal with this sort of scenario, but making one object that implements both behaviours poorly isn't a good choice.

Hard to say which option would be best, but a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with a converter from and perhaps to the EF representation would be a much better solution than leaving a huge hole in the logic to fall into later.

Comment: Can you show an example of what it would look like if I filled the set. Maybe I will understand what your saying better. Since I am using Entity Framework and extending with a partial class should I be using private properties for setting?

Comment: Based on your now expanded scenario I would not do that. I've no idea what it could look like, depends on what values, you expect to be sent to the setter. One of my all time favourite bug reports, was "If you put the first name in the last name box, and the last name in the first name box, the name comes out backwards on the report".  Exactly this scenario. save yourself some pain.

Comment: So is the only solution to avoid using a FullName field all together and everywhere in my code use the individual FirstName and LastName fields? Then when binding my grid use FirstName + ' ' + LastName.

Comment: No it's not the only solution. Just try not pick one that causes more problems than it solves. I can't say what that should be from here.